# visible, non-interactive elements with an on:click event must be accompanied by an on:keydown, on:keyup, or on:keypress event

Tags: dom-events, accessibility, svelte, sveltekit

> A11y: visible, non-interactive elements with an on:click event must be accompanied by an on:keydown, on:keyup, or on:keypress event.svelte (a11y-click-events-have-key-events)

what does this error mean ?  I am getting it too much in sveltekit. When I want to add an event listener on click this warning show me. Even event handler is not empty. below my code.

```
<div
    class="select-options max-h-0 transition-all duration-300 bg-slate-100"
    data-target="option-selection-wrapper"
    >
    {#each options as item}
        <div class="border py-1 border-dark-300 px-3 text-sm" on:click={()=> {
            selectedItem = item
        }}>
            {@html item.name}
        </div>
    {/each}
</div>
```

is there any possible way to remove this warning. and why does this warning shows.

Comment: But does anyone know how to just fix this by adding those events and the aria tag? The only answer is about disabling the warning.

Answer (score 29):

The warning shows up because if you add click handlers to non-interactive elements, they cannot be interacted with via the keyboard which is important for accessibility. Try to interact with your application without using the mouse and see how far you get.

Things that can be clicked should always use `button` elements (unless it's about navigation, that should use `<a>`).

(The message should be more helpful in newer versions of Svelte. [The docs](https://svelte.dev/docs/accessibility-warnings#a11y-click-events-have-key-events) now have more info on this, as well.)

Comment: In addition to keyboard event handlers, you will **also need** `tabindex="0"` (if you're not using a natively interactive element such as a `<button>`, as suggested) so that you can TAB to the element **AND** your interactive element **must have** a [role](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#role_definitions) such as `role="button"` or `role="checkbox"` or `role="radio"`, depending, of course, on the purpose of your interactive element.

Comment: but adding tabindex will trigger another warning, which is "no-noninteractive-tabindex" :-/ I wish svelte would add a tutorial for accessibility, to complement these warnings

Comment: @Eskel: As noted, please just use buttons. And yes, the documentation could be better.

Comment: @slugolicious when adding "role="button"" to a button element you get this warning : 
A11y: Redundant role 'button' - svelte(a11y-no-redundant-roles)

Comment: @JayD., of course that's redundant. No one said to add `role="button"` to a `<button>`. The OP was using a `<div>`. The div needs a role, keyboard event handlers, and tabindex in order for it to be accessible. But that's a lot of work when you could easily use a real `<button>`.

Answer (score 16):

##### If you want to disable these warnings:

Add this in your `svelte.config.js`:

```js
const config = {
  // ...
  onwarn: (warning, handler) => {
    if (warning.code === 'a11y-click-events-have-key-events') return
    handler(warning)
  },
}
```

You can even disable all a11y warning logs using:

```js
const config = {
  // ...
  onwarn: (warning, handler) => {
    if (warning.code.startsWith('a11y-')) return
    handler(warning)
  },
}
```

###### If you want to remove warnings in VSCode

Add this to your `eslintrc.cjs`

```js
module.exports = {
  //..
  settings: {
    //...
    'svelte3/ignore-warnings': (warning) => {
      return warning.code === 'a11y-click-events-have-key-events'
    },
  },
}
```

Add this to your `.vscode/settings.json`

```js
"svelte.plugin.svelte.compilerWarnings": {
  "a11y-click-events-have-key-events": "ignore",
},
```

Comment: Props for the onwarn handler trick. Given the compiler doesn't actually say _which_ rule is being violated, this allowed me to console log the warn and see the rule name

Answer (score 4):

You can, with a lot of work, make a div for without the warning and with the functionality needed to make is accessible. I know I've occasionally done this and put an SVG inside the div to make any kind of graphic control.

```
<div role="button"
tabindex="0"
on:click={actLikeaButton}
on:keydown={actLikeaButton}
aria-label="PANIC!"
class="shiny-red-button">
Panic!
</div>
```

Comment: I have done the same